Disadvantages of Randomized Numerical Linear Algebra
After reading the paper: "Finding Structure with Randomness: Probabilistic Algorithms for Constructing Approximate Matrix Decompositions" by N. Halko, P. G. Martinssin and J. A Tropp, I was wondering about the disadvantages of using randomization in numerical linear algebra.
I looked at some surveys, and one disadvantage I found was the fact that with randomization, the results are not reproducible.
Other than that, I haven't found any major disadvantages. I am curious, as I'm aware of the fact in practice, the deterministic classical algorithms are still being used more widely than their random counterparts.
I was looking for an explanation for that phenomenon, and specifically - for some disadvantages of the random approach compared to the deterministic approach.
Thanks in advance!

There are many cases where the random approach provides in an easy way (quickly written program) a result with 2 or 3 decimals which is often enough for practical purposes  ("quick and dirty" way but efficient) .

Hey @JeanMarie, thank you very much for your comment!
The thing is, that I'm aware of most of the advantages of the randomized approach (they are amplified in most of the relevant papers/surveys), However, I do want to learn about some disadvantages of the randomized approach, which aren't discussed as often.

Randomized results are reproducible if you specify the random seed used in your computing environment. This is becoming more common in published code, but it unfortunately not standard yet. One genuine disadvantage is that many methods require some amount of oversampling to be accurate, so memory can become an issue.
Another potential drawback is that error analysis becomes significantly more complicated. For example, suppose you compute a randomized SVD and project some high-dimensional model onto the subspace spanned by the first $k$ left singular vectors. With deterministic algorithms, we have pretty good bounds as to how close this subspace is to the "true" subspace in infinite-precision arithmetic. With randomized algorithms, more analysis needs to be to determine whether the potential random error in the subspace affects our projected model. Maybe the first singular vector has lower variance, maybe it depends on the gaps between singular values, maybe we need more samples to robustly estimate $k$ dimensions compared to, say, $k/2$. Repeat this questioning for every type of matrix decomposition and you can see that the number of things to keep track of grows quite quickly. There are simply more decision points for practitioners that necessitate more knowledge of current research.
